# Jquery checkbox not checked when all subitems are checked in C# MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have this Loop here that generate checkboxes from sites to floor to rooms and when I check on the sites all the floors are checked but the reverse way round if I manually check all floors but the site check box is not checked. please help fix my mistakes

```
<div class="form-group ">
  <ul id="siterecord">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.SASites.Count; i++)
    {
      @*Generate the sites*@
      <li>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SASites[i].IsCheck, new { @class = "parent" })
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SASites[i].IsCheck, Model.SASites[i].SiteName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SASites[i].SiteId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SASites[i].SiteName)
        @*Generate the floors for each site*@
        @for (int j = 0; j < Model.SASites[i].SAFloors.Count; j++)
        {
          <div style="margin-left:50px; clear:both;">
            <label>Floor @Model.SASites[i].SAFloors[j].FloorName</label>
          </div>
          <br />
          <div style="margin-left:20px;">
            <ul class="suiterecord">
              @for (int k = 0; k < Model.SASites[i].SAFloors[j].SARooms.Count; k++)
              {
                <li style="float:left;">
                  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SASites[i].SAFloors[j].SARooms[k].IsCheck, new { @class = "child chkboxCss" })
                  <div class="ARSLabel">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SASites[i].SAFloors[j].SARooms[k].IsCheck, Model.SASites[i].SAFloors[j].SARooms[k].RoomName)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SASites[i].SAFloors[j].SARooms[k].RoomId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SASites[i].SAFloors[j].SARooms[k].RoomName)
                  </div>
                </li>
                if ((k + 1) % 5 == 0)
                {
                  @Html.Raw("</ul><div style='clear:both'></div><br><ul class='suiterecord'>");
                }
              }
            </ul>
            <div style='clear:both'></div><br>
          </div>
        }
      </li>
    }
  </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery script

```
<script>
$('.parent').click(function () {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    var children = $(this).closest('li').find('.child');
    $.each(children, function (index, item) {
        $(this).prop('checked', isChecked);
    });
});

$('.child').click(function () {
    var parent = $(this).closest('li').find('.parent');
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    if (!isChecked) {
        // the parent must be unchecked
        parent.prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        // check if all siblings have the same checked status
        var siblings = $(this).siblings('.child');
        var total = siblings.length;
        var matches = siblings.filter(function () {
            return $(this).prop('checked') == isChecked;
        }).length;
        if (matches === total) {
            parent.prop('checked', isChecked);
        }
    }
})
```

My Code now is working fine with checking the parent all the child item is checked. but it is not working the other way round whereby check all child the parent is not checked

Output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeqFC.png)

Comment: Can you please post your output HTML Structure, It is difficult to understand how your HTML structure will come.

Comment: @Samir i have upload a image of the outcome

Comment: Can you please add the HTML structure, With simply by image (posted by you) is very difficult to get the HTML structure, We have play with the parent/child combination. If you provide the HTMl then it will be easy to write the script.

Comment: @samir I'm using Razor View in MVC. only this part that does the looping others C# codes are not relevant to this. It was all working until i added a new label loop you can check out the old codes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40483523/jquery-check-all-dynamic-checkboxlist-in-mvc-view/40483866?noredirect=1#comment68244117_40483866

Comment: In your browser debugger, you are getting the proper HTML correct? Just copy that HTML structure from debugger and post it here. I tried to prepare a HTML w.r.t your Looping, but even if i succeeded, it might be the case some where i miss some tag and due to that the script will break, which i don't want.

Comment: Ok get what you mean now. will do it shortly current away for awhile thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you want to check all the children when the parent is checked, and check the parent when all the children are checked.

Maybe this fiddle, I developed can help you:

https://jsfiddle.net/xcbq4nb1/2/

What it does is to check the parent when all the children are selected, but not viceversa (i.e if all children are deselected, the parent is still selected, this is done on purpose, but you can tweak it as it depends on the context you are working with). Also, when you check/uncheck the parent, all the children check/uncheck with it (this is tweakable too).

The code is the following :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".parent > div >input").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".parent").find(".children input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked",$(this).is(":checked"));
  });

  $(".children li > input").click(function(event) {
    var parent = $(this).closest(".parent");
    var chldContainer = parent.find(".children");
    var checkedChildren = chldContainer.find("li input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").length;
    if (checkedChildren == 0 && parent.find("input").is(":not(:checked)")) {
        $(this).closest(".parent").find("div > input").prop("checked", true);
    } 
  });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply select all the checkboxes and use `.prop('checked', false)` to uncheck them. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'input#all', function(){
    var isChecked = $('input#all:checked').length > 0 ? true : false;
    $('.rooms').find('.rcb').prop('checked', isChecked);
  })
})
```

Here is a working fiddle demonstrating both `checking` and `unchecking`:

> https://jsfiddle.net/94d0f6m0/1/

Also it is a good idea to use `.on` instead of directly using `.click` if you generate the checkboxes after the DOM has been loaded for making sure that your code also watches for checkbox elements dynamically added to the DOM after it has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

try this simple function

```
$('.child').click(function () {
   var parent = $(this).closest('li');//get the parent
   var all = parent.find('.child').length;//get all childs
   var allChecked = parent.find('.child:checked').length;//get all checked
    parent.find('.parent').prop('checked', false);//uncheck
  if(all == allChecked) {
   parent.find('.parent').prop('checked', true);//check if all are checked
  }
})
```

Comment: No idea where go wrong. previously it was working perfectly. after a change of requirement i add in another loop to the label part then its not working. but selecting parent is working fine now too, just the childs not working

Comment: paste the parsed html so we may help you